# How should I populate data in an express.js page layout

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a fairly standard requirement for a web app where most of the pages will be rendered with a single layout (I'm using handlebars but the same would apply to Jade or anything else).

The layout uses quite a bit of data from the database and may require several lookups.  How should I structure the code so that the data used by the layout does not have to be retrieved in each controller for each page/route?  In many web frameworks there is a simple way to intercept routes by pattern and have that interceptor make the required lookups, decorating the model generated by the controller that they wrap.

It feels like there should be some way to do that with the right definition of middlewares, but I can't figure it out.

Looking for something that does what my pseudo-code below shows:

```
router.get('/', ctrlPublic.index);
router.get('/index.html', ctrlPublic.index);
router.get('/find-us.html', ctrlPublic.findUs);

// apply same interceptor to all (/*)
router.intercept('/*', ctrlDecorator.main);

// ctrlPublic...
index: function(req, res) {
    // get data for index page, then render index.hbs
},
findUs: function(req, res) {
    // get data for find-us page, then render find-us.hbs
}

// ctrlDecorator...
main: function(req, res) {
    // lookup data needed by main layout - this gets automatically 
    // added to the model used by the page ctrlPublic handlers
}
```

I would ideally like interceptors target the controllers by pattern matching rather than declaration in the `router.get()` call, and for them to be additive so that more than one could apply to a certain set of controllers.

Is there a module that helps with this, or just a general "best practice" way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question right you need a global middleware to fetch the data and pass it to the respective controller so you dont load the same layout data on the controller right?

In that case create a global middleware

```
 app.use(function(req, res, next){
    var excludeMiddleware = ['login', 'test', 'test2'];
    //simple example for bypassing the middleware
    for(var i = 0; i < excludeMiddleware.length; i++){
       if(excludeMiddleware[i] === req.path) { return next(); }
    }                

    someAsyncFnFromDb.then(function(dataFromDb){
       //req.layoutData = dataFromDb;          
       res.locals.layoutData  = dataFromDb;
       return next();
    }).catch(function(err){
       return next(); // or throw new Error(err)
    });
});
```

and in your controller assign the data to the render function if you use `req.layoutData`, example

```
res.render('myView', { layoutData: req.layoutData });
```

or leave your controller as is if you use `res.locals.layoutData` and the layoutData will be available on your view.

Comment: yes, your understanding of the use of data is right, and a solution like that would be amenable to caching the layout data too which I also need.  But it seems inelegant in that a change to how the middleware is used involves changing the declaration of potentially many controllers and routes.  Could such a middleware be applied by convention or pattern matching for example, rather than repeating it in every controller?

Comment: if you define that middleware before you define any route it will be automatically injected in every route and if you change `req.layoutData = dataFromDb;` to `res.locals.layoutData  = dataFromDb;` then you dont need to change anything on your controllers the layoutData will be available on every template.Now for the pattern matching you could exclude some routes if you dont need to load the layoutData i made an example look at the updated answer.

Comment: ok, yes, it's better but interceptors (middleware) knowing about controllers  in order to exclude them is kinda backwards.  I was at first a little surprised, I assumed I was missing some first-class functionality of express because every web framework I've used in every other language has something of that nature.  I guess sailsjs.org is what provides this higher level set of functionality for express apps.. seems to be more what I'm after from glancing over it.

Comment: you dont need to know the controller just the router path you need something to match so you can exclude or you could use named paths or some other identifier.